# EKRecurrenceRule not saved with EKEvent

Tags: objective-c

I have an app running, which worked just fine until iOS11. Among many other things, it sets up EKEvents with recurrence. Those events still copy to the calendar as expected, but without the recurrence. And the recurrence vanishes after saving the event.

That's how I'm doing it:

```
       EKEventStore *newStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    
        // define new EKEvent
        EKEvent *newEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:newStore];
        newEvent.calendar = [ResourceManager sharedResourceManager].selectedCalendar;
        newEvent.allDay = TRUE;
        newEvent.startDate = loopNSDate;
        newEvent.endDate = loopNSDate;
        newEvent.availability = EKEventAvailabilityFree;            
        
        EKRecurrenceRule *rule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc]
                                  initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily
                                  interval:diensteInPlan
                                  end:end];
        
        NSArray *recurrenceRulesForDate = @[rule];
        
        newEvent.recurrenceRules = recurrenceRulesForDate;
        
        newEvent.title = @"EventTitle";
        newEvent.notes = note;
        
        NSError *error = nil;

        [newStore saveEvent:newEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent  error:&error];
```

NSLOGging the newEvent before "saveEvent..." shows an event with the correct recurrence. But NSLogging it afterwards shows the same event - but with (nill) as recurrence.

Am I missing something here? Many thanks in advance.